# Почему flex элемент игнорирует указанную ширину?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

div c классом videoInadvantageLund имеет заданную ширину 565px, по факту в браузере он имеет размер 386,64px. Причем он ведет себя так, только когда является flex элементом. Когда я у родителя убираю display: flex, элемент принимает заданные размеры.

p.s В дублирующем блоке, который находится ниже, вместо div есть img, с ней таких проблем нет, она занимает свой фактический размер.

HTML:

```
<section class="advantageLund">
    <h2>Баланс прочности и надежности</h2>
    <div class="contentadvantageLund">
        <div class="blockContentAdvantageLund">
            <div class="videoInadvantageLund">
            </div>
            <div class="descriptionAdvantageLund">
                <h3>Непревзойденная производительность</h3>
                <p>Технология IPS, IPS2, и IPS3 Lund исключительная обеспечивает бесподобный контроль и более ровную, более сухую езду.</p>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="blockContentAdvantageLund">
            <div class="descriptionAdvantageLund">
                <h3>Непревзойденная производительность</h3>
                <p>Технология IPS, IPS2, и IPS3 Lund исключительная обеспечивает бесподобный контроль и более ровную, более сухую езду.</p>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <img src="image/banners/banner-advantage.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
/* Start advantage Lund */
.advantageLund {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fbfbfd;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 86px 0 107px 0;
}
.advantageLund > h2 {
  color: #333333;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 36.71px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4.8px;
  margin-bottom: 87px;
}
.contentadvantageLund {
  width: 63vw;
  max-width: 1209px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.blockContentAdvantageLund {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.blockContentAdvantageLund > img:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-right: 113px;
}
.blockContentAdvantageLund > img:nth-child(even) {
  margin-left: 113px;
}
.blockContentAdvantageLund:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 53px;
}

.descriptionAdvantageLund > h3 {
  color: #96050b;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 56px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}
.descriptionAdvantageLund > p {
  color: #12132a;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 41px;
  margin-bottom: 39px;
}
.descriptionAdvantageLund > hr {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 86%;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #96050b;
}
/* End Advantage Lund  */
.videoInadvantageLund {
  width: 565px;
  height: 400px;
  background: url(../image/logo/maxresdefault.webp) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так задайте: `flex-shrink: 0;` для `.videoInadvantageLund` и будет счастье.

```css
/* Start advantage Lund */
.advantageLund {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fbfbfd;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 86px 0 107px 0;
}
.advantageLund > h2 {
  color: #333333;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 36.71px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4.8px;
  margin-bottom: 87px;
}
.contentadvantageLund {
  width: 63vw;
  max-width: 1209px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.blockContentAdvantageLund {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.blockContentAdvantageLund > img:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-right: 113px;
}
.blockContentAdvantageLund > img:nth-child(even) {
  margin-left: 113px;
}
.blockContentAdvantageLund:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 53px;
}

.descriptionAdvantageLund > h3 {
  color: #96050b;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 56px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}
.descriptionAdvantageLund > p {
  color: #12132a;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 41px;
  margin-bottom: 39px;
}
.descriptionAdvantageLund > hr {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 86%;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #96050b;
}
/* End Advantage Lund  */
.videoInadvantageLund {
  width: 565px;
  height: 400px;
  background: url(../image/logo/maxresdefault.webp) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<section class="advantageLund">
    <h2>Баланс прочности и надежности</h2>
    <div class="contentadvantageLund">
        <div class="blockContentAdvantageLund">
            <div class="videoInadvantageLund">
            </div>
            <div class="descriptionAdvantageLund">
                <h3>Непревзойденная производительность</h3>
                <p>Технология IPS, IPS2, и IPS3 Lund исключительная обеспечивает бесподобный контроль и более ровную, более сухую езду.</p>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="blockContentAdvantageLund">
            <div class="descriptionAdvantageLund">
                <h3>Непревзойденная производительность</h3>
                <p>Технология IPS, IPS2, и IPS3 Lund исключительная обеспечивает бесподобный контроль и более ровную, более сухую езду.</p>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <img src="image/banners/banner-advantage.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо, совсем забыл про это свойство.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема решается либо добавлением `flex-shrink: 0;` к `.videoInadvantageLund`, как указали выше, либо добавлением min-width к оному элементу. В обеих случаях элемент не дает себя сжимать, но вариант с flex-shrink  более грамотный.